# Опустить list-item-image

Tags: изображения, css

Использую картинку в качестве `list-item`, но она немного не подходит по размерам. Можно ли опустить на 2 пикселя картинку, или поднять текст не поднимая `list-item`.

Comment: Используйте картинку, как бэкграунд. Меньше гемороя.

Comment: ul.menu li {background:url('some.png') 10px center no-repeat;}